# python dbf query between two dates

Tags: python, dbf

I am using [dbf module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf/). I need to search (query) all the products where invoice date between 2023-01-23 to 2023-01-25, include both dates.

I have dbf table ( product.dbf ) with below data

```
invno  invdt       hsn        mname          packg    
2010 2023-01-21 30086666     Medicine01     10'S  
2010 2023-01-23 30044444     Medicine02      10'S   
2010 2023-01-23 30043333     Medicine03      15'S   
2010 2023-01-23 30049999     Medicine04      15'S  
2011 2023-01-24 30049999     Medicine05      15'S  
2011 2023-01-24 30049999     Medicine06      15'S    
2011 2023-01-24 30049444     Medicine07      30'ML  
2011 2023-01-24 30049333     Medicine08      30'ML   
2011 2023-01-26 30049111     Medicine09      30'ML   
2011 2023-01-26 30049111     Medicine09      30'ML   
2012 2023-01-31 30042333     Medicine10      60'S    
2012 2023-01-31 30042234     Medicine11      15'S
```

I am trying with below code, it is not working as expected.
I am getting exception when exact date is not there in the table. example if 25-01-2023 is not there,  then below exception will be displayed

> **dbf.NotFoundError: 'dbf.Index.index_search(x): x not in Index'**

```
import dbf
import datetime

table = dbf.Table('product.dbf')
table.open(dbf.READ_ONLY)

index = table.create_index(lambda rec: rec.invdt)

# search between 2023-01-23 to 2023-01-25, include both dates.
fromdate = index.index_search(match=(datetime.datetime.strptime('23-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y').date()))
todate = index.index_search(match=(datetime.datetime.strptime('25-01-2023','%d-%m-%Y').date()))

for row in index[fromdate:todate]:
    print(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4])

# Same way below code also throw exception for invoice range, 
# where from or to invoice number(here invoice 2015) is not found.

index = table.create_index(lambda rec: rec.invno)

# search between 2010 to 2015 include both invno.
frominv = index.index_search(match=(2010,))
toinv = index.index_search(match=(2015,))

    
table.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare 2023-01-25 to 25-01-2023?

It would be easier to do a comparison like this

```
import pandas as pd
from simpledbf import Dbf5

dbf = Dbf5('product.dbf')
table = dbf.to_dataframe()
desiredRange = table.loc[(table['invdt'] >= start_date) & (table['invdt'] <= end_date)]
```

Comment: it is working fine.

But I used [dbf module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf/) in my whole project, so I need solution using dbf module only

Answer (score 0):

If a missing value is acceptable (which it appears to be in your case), add `nearest=True`:

```
fromdate = index.index_search(match=(datetime...).date(), nearest=True)
```

`fromdate` will be an `IndexLocation`, which is a subtype of `int` (`long` in Python 2.7) and has a `found` attribute.  `found` will be `True` or `False`, but since you are using `fromdate` and `todate` in ranges you won't need that.

---

Looking a bit closer, what you really want is to use `index.query`*:

```
start_date = dbf.Date('2023-01-23')
end_date = dbf.date('2023-01-25')
for row in index.query(lambda rec: start_date <= rec.invdt <= end_date):
    # do something
```

---

* this is not an SQL engine.

Comment: I added nearest=True in index_search. now there is no exception dbf.NotFoundError: 'dbf.Index.index_search(x): x not in Index'. but return value become 0. No matching record index returned, it is always 0 only.

Comment: @RaviKannan: I just tested using your data above, and got `fromdate==1` and `todate==8` for the values.

Comment: I tried with your first suggestion nearest=True, it is working. It is my mistake, there was no data in the table, because of that I got 0.

I tried with your second suggestion index.query is not working and throw AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'upper'.     

start_date = dbf.Date('2023-01-23')
end_date = dbf.Date('2023-01-25')     
or      
start_date = dbf.Date(2023,1,23)
end_date = dbf.Date(2023,1,25)

Comment: Also, could you please clarify the difference between partial=True and nearest=True?
When should I use partial=True and nearest=True

Where can I get complete dbf module (functions syntax) documentation.
I found some example [here](https://github.com/ethanfurman/dbf/blob/master/dbf/README.md)